gitkraken conflicts prevent checkout
I am using GitKraken and am currently trying to change from the feature branch to the develop branch, but an error saying conflicts prevent checkout. What should I do? It has currently been merged into develop, but the feature branch is still alive and not closed. It says to commit, stash, or discard first, What should I do?
Currently, I can't do anything because I don't know what to do first. I can see that it has been merged into develop, but I can still see the feature branch.

Why did you tag your question with intellij-idea and gitkraken? If you use IDEA why don't you use also the built in version control system? It would allow you to do kind of an "intelligent" checkout where you get your local changes applied to your newly checked out branch.

You must commit your changes on your feature branch before you can switch to another branch.

This means that you have uncommitted changes in your workspace. You can either do one of the three options it gave you:

commit - add your dangling changes to your feature branch (for a later merge)
stash - put your changes aside and reset your feature branch to a state before you made them
discard - loose the local changes

Another option would be to check out the branch you want to switch to into a complete fresh folder on your disk and decide later what you want to do with that, but I would recommend to do that only temporarily - the mentioned three options above are probably better for you.
